# Yii All post requests fail CSRF validation only for first time session

Tags: php, session, yii, csrf

I am using this post to get/set csrf token using sessions with no changes to the code

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/274/how-to-validate-csrf-token-with-session/

If the user lands on page for the first time ever and then performs POST requests, all of them fail. (all POST requests send the CSRF Token). But if the user refreshes the page then all POST requests after the reload will pass!

after a lot of debugging, i found that the CSRF Token that I receive on first page load will no longer match the value saved in the session. When the user reloads the page, the csrf token gets changed to the value of the CSRF session and all POST requests succeed.

I have session autostart set to true. I also tried using cookies instead on sessions  but the same issue happens. I also tried user state.

I might have had this issue since i first started this 1 year project but never noticed it until now, it only happens if its the first time loads the page.

All my Controllers extend a ParentController which  extends Controller. It only has a constructor and init.
I tried to find out if its being called twice but so far nothing.

```
 public function __construct($id,$module=null)
 {

       parent::__construct($id,$module);    

        // do stuff
 }
 public function init()
{       
        // do stuff
 }
```

below is an example of the POST request after page load

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {name:xName,id:xID,YII_CSRF_TOKEN:CSRFTokenValue},
   url: "/page/logPageView/",
   success: function(data){
   }
});
```

Any Ideas on where else i should look? any possible causes for such a strange behavior?

Comment: Add some debug info in CHttpRequest::validateCsrfToken() - dump $userToken and $cookies variables - it will probably give you something to think about - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L1239

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue is is related to caching. I recently added cloudflare caching which caused the first time user to get an old CSRF token from the cached content. That's the reason why i was not able to regenerate it on my localhost or testing server as they are not cached.

I solved this by adding an ajax call to get a fresh token on page load and then use this token for future posts. and make sure the "getFreshToken" call is not cached.

Comment: Do you know if that can be accomplished in yii2 ?
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/73114-csrf-token-in-yii2-and-cloudflarefull-page-caching/

How did you do that? With a post request ?